# calculate difference in times over days c#

Tags: c#, wpf, timer

I am trying get setup a Recording Time label so that when a user clicks a button it starts and when they click another button it stops.

I have tried two different things which have not worked.

1. **Setting a Ticker and increment a value by 1 and displaying it.**

*This did not work as i am also doing other things in the ticker which means it might take 1.5 seconds but i'm increment by 1, therefore the longer the recording goes on the more inaccruate it is.*

2. **Getting the TimeOfDay when the stream starts and on the ticker method getting the TimeOfDay and subtracting them.**

*This is not working because if the recording is left overnight the time turns into minuses I.E -67647.74 seconds.*

```
private void StreamClick_Click(object obj)
{
    _streamStartTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
}

private void LiveVideoStream_Tick(VideoCaptureDevice cam)
{
    _currentRecordTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay - _streamStartTime;
    RecordTime = _currentRecordTime.ToString();
}
```

Does anyone have any other ideas how I can display a nice timer.

Comment: Don't rely on just the time, but subtract the entire DateTimes from each other.

Comment: `_streamStartTime` should be a `DateTime` too, then assign it with `DateTime.Now` when you click. minus the two values, you got `TimeSpan`, use the `TimeSpan`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `_streamStartTime` should be a `DateTime` too. Then in your `Click` event handler, assign `DateTime.Now` to it, don't use `TimeOfDay` only:

```
private void StreamClick_Click(object obj)
{
    _streamStartTime = DateTime.Now;
}
```

Then in your calculation, you simply need to negate the two `DateTime` to get `TimeSpan`. Use the `TimeSpan` to produce your time `string`:

```
private void LiveVideoStream_Tick(VideoCaptureDevice cam)
{
    TimeSpan _currentRecordTime = DateTime.Now - _streamStartTime;
    string RecordTime = _currentRecordTime.TotalDays.ToString() + " " + _currentRecordTime.Hours.ToString() + ":" + 
        _currentRecordTime.Minutes.ToString() + ":" + _currentRecordTime.Seconds.ToString();

}
```

Comment: In the click I can't assign `DateTime.Now` as that is not a `TimeSpan`?

Comment: The important point is your `_streamStartTime` should be a `DateTime`. Then when you minus two `DateTime`, you would get a `TimeSpan`. `TimeSpan` is a great `struct` to deal with time difference. It has a lot of useful property/fields like Days, Hours, Minutes, Seconds, Milliseconds, as well as TotalDays, TotalHours, TotalMinutes, TotalSeconds, etc... try that out!

Comment: Yes this now seems to work. `TimeSpan` does give a lot of properties. One issue, Instead of me using `'.TotalDays'` can i use `'.Days'` as `'.TotalDays'` is returning me a huge number and i just want to display numbers like `0,1,2,3,4,5`.

Comment: Then you may want to cast your `TotalDays` to `int`, just to get rid of the fraction. You could also use `Math.Round`. Something like `((int)(_currentRecordTime.TotalDays)).ToString()`. Alternatively, just use the `Days`

Answer (score 1):

Do not use DateTime.Now because the system clock can jump backwards or forwards on rare occasions. DateTime.UtcNow is a lot safer - no daylight saving - but still not bulletproof.

You should use StopWatch instead.

Comment: I am a bit late, but I must agree with that this is the "safest" solution.